# Why "Throttle...Open 1/2 travel" on engine troubleshoot checklist?

Tags: emergency-procedures, engine-failure, checklist

Why do some engine troubleshoot checklists (on small single engine piston aircraft) call for throttle to only be open 1/2 travel? I suspect it has something to do with modern fuel injected engines, but haven't found anything explaining why half throttle, instead of full throttle.

Below is an example, however, I saw at least one other checklist online for another single engine piston (non-Cessna) that had similar "1/2 open" throttle language.

[image]

Comment: Troubleshooting what?  Flooding?

Comment: Is this an in flight check list or on ground?

Comment: The tags say engine failure, but the question doesn't make that clear.

Comment: Can you copy and paste a specific checklist, to make sure we understand what you're asking?

Comment: @Pondlife see screenshot. I saw another checklist online for different SEL piston aircraft with same 1/2 throttle language, but couldn't find it again. This appears to be the checklist for partial or total engine failure, presumably in-flight, not engine failure on take-off.

Comment: "Modern fuel-injected engines" are rare as hens teeth in light, GA aircraft. See the (approximately) 1,843 questions here as to why.

Answer (score 3):

Revised following update to OP:

If the engine quits and you're gliding along with it windmilling and the throttle pulled back to idle, if it comes to life at some point, you may not even be aware of it because you can barely tell the difference between off and idling when it's windmilling in a glide.  On the other hand, pushing it full forward isn't such a good idea either.

You want it set to a power setting that makes it obvious it's come back to life, but you don't want to set it to full throttle because you don't want it going full bore instantly, which is generally not helpful to the engine because the oil pump may only be making 20 or 30 psi while windmilling, or none at all if it stops windmilling, and full power before the oil pressure can catch up is murder on the plain bearings of the crank journals that depend on oil pressure to keep crank journal and bearing separated from physical contact.

So half throttle makes a nice compromise.